# como poner dos TextFormField uno al lado del otro

Tags: formularios, text

body: Container(
child: SingleChildScrollView(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
child: Form(
key: _formKey,
child: Column(children: [
TextFormField(
style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
decoration: const InputDecoration(
labelText: "Nombre(s)",
border: OutlineInputBorder()
),
textAlign: TextAlign.left, validator: (text) {
if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
return 'Campo vacio';
}
return null;
},
),
const SizedBox(height: 15,),
TextFormField(
style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
decoration: const InputDecoration(
labelText: "Apellidos",
border: OutlineInputBorder()
),
textAlign: TextAlign.left, validator: (text) {
if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
return 'Campo vacio';
}
return null;
},
),

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: lo que necesito es poner dos textFormField ejemplo _______dato_____   _______dato_______